# Signal strength average from iw

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I was using `iw dev wlan0 station dump` to get signal strength in an ad-hoc network, and noticed the output has a `signal avg` row. As average signal strength is actually what I'm interested in, this could be very useful, but I can't seem to be able to find over which period is this average calculated anywhere. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks

Comment: This is Linux. Look at the source for `iw`. `sudo apt-get install apt-src` and use it to grab the source.